# SQL: Showing all the products for each month even when

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that shows me all the products for each month, but I get stuck, because if a product its not sold in a certain month it wont appear, and I want to pass the value from month to month progressive.

For example like in this Picture:[image]

You can see that for February I've got OLD and ORD, but because in March and April there was no Products sold I can't see, neither in May because there was no OLD product sold it wont appear. I want for each month to have all products, even if in the beginning its null.

Something like that:

> February 2015:
>
> 0-OIR, 2-OLD, 2-ORD
>
> March 2015:0-OIR, 2-OLD, 2-ORD
>
> April 2015:0-OIR, 2-OLD, 2-ORD
>
> May 2015:1-OIR,2-OLD, 5-ORD
>
> June 2015: 1-OIR, 2-OLD, 7-ORD

and so on this table goes until current date

The column from the left its Cumulative summing per product and in the right between year and month its Cumulative summing for all products.

The query looks like this.

```
    select  
    sum(a.count) over (partition by [Product Name] ORDER BY Year,Month) as 'Sum Per Product'
    ,a.[Product Name]
    ,a.month
    ,a.Year
    ,sum(a.Count) OVER (ORDER BY Year,Month) as 'Cumulative Sum of all products'

    ,
    case
    a.Month
    when 1 then 'January'
    when 2 then 'February'
    when 3 then 'March'
    when 4 then 'April'
    when 5 then 'May' 
    when 6 then 'June' 
    when 7 then 'July' 
    when 8 then 'August' 
    when 9 then 'September' 
    when 10 then 'October' 
    when 11 then 'November' 
    when 12 then 'December' 
    end [months]
from (
SELECT 

    count(COALESCE(p.ShortName + ' ' ,'No Product')) as 'Count'
    ,COALESCE(p.ShortName + ' ' ,'No Product') as 'Product Name'
    ,MONTH(m.CreatedDatetime) AS 'Month'
   ,YEAR(m.CreatedDatetime) AS 'Year'



FROM Request r

LEFT JOIN Contact c on r.ContactId = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Machine m on r.machineId = m.ID
LEFT JOIN MachineStatus ms on m.active = ms.ID
 join machineProduct mp on m.Id=mp.MachineId
LEFT JOIN RequestProduct rp on r.ID = rp.RequestId
LEFT JOIN ProductVersion pv on pv.ID = rp.ProductVersionId
LEFT JOIN Product p on pv.ProductId = p.ID




WHERE 
 m.statusid in (1,2)
GROUP BY  COALESCE(p.ShortName + ' ' ,'No Product'), YEAR(m.CreatedDatetime),MONTH(m.CreatedDatetime)) a

group by Month,Year,a.count,a.[Product Name]
Order by a.Year,a.Month,a.[Product Name],[months]
```

EDIT:

I've created a temporary table that looks like this but how can I connect it to my main query to retrieve the info from Temp Table + The 2 Columns Cumulative summing per product and Cumulative summing for all products.

The query looks like this

```
`Declare @temp table 
(id int
,name nvarchar(40)
,yeari int
,monthi int
)

-


Insert into @temp (id,name,yeari,monthi) (Select prd.id,prd.shortname,mac.yeari,mac.monthi 
            from (Select  id,shortname from Product where Product.Active=1) prd
            cross join (select distinct year(m.createddatetime) as yeari
                        ,month(m.createddatetime) as monthi
FROM machine m 
) mac)`
```

The Output looks like this:

[image]

How can I connect them?

Comment: Your query is too large for an exact answer, but long story short you need to join with a calendar table containing all months/years which you want to appear in your report.  SQL is good for extracting information, but not so much for creating new information.

Comment: I've edited with the table that you said but if you could help me to connect them will be nice.

Comment: Have a look at this answer to a similar question on using a calendar table to generate a report. In your case, you may also need to cross join dates to products. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052087/5790584

Comment: Thanks @EricBrandt that helped me out with my problem, solved my issue.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!